# Python 3.4.3 + Current PyQt5, DLL load failed

Tags: python, qt, dll, python-3.4, python-3.5

When trying to run a simple test of a database.py:

```
import pymysql.cursor
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QTimer
```

This the output in the Exceptions tab of WingWare IDE:

```
File       "c:\MyProjects\___MECHANIKOS\UltraSimpleSarlaccPit\01_UltraSimpleSarlaccPit.py",   line 1, in <module>
  from database import Database
￼ File "c:\MyProjects\___MECHANIKOS\UltraSimpleSarlaccPit\database.py", line 2, in <module>
  from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QObject, QTimer

builtins.ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`
```

There was an error when installing PyQt5 that says it was built for 3.5 not 3.4.  So is that why?
If so, where can we download a 3.4.3 compatible version?

Thanks!

Regards,
Team Mechanikos

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to 3.5:

1. Uninstall old PyQt5 and Python 3.4.3 through control panel > Programs
2. Install python 3.5.1, specifying making sure you specify C:\Python35\ as install location.
3. Install PyQt5 for 3.5 (Current).

Works.

Comment: This is great information! I'll forward it to our lead developer. We didn't want the thing to stall out on gigs of information and not know what was happening.